# custom color palette , extract function from colorspace::choose_palette() wizard

Tags: r

I need to realize a custom color palette (I don't like presets available). I find a usefull function from colorspace package that allows to create a palette using a simple GUI. The function is
`choose_palette()` 
Using the GUI it's possible to select colors, luminance, etc...
What I want to do is to get the function tha generates my custom palette, se workflow below:

```
library(colorspace)

#I create my custom palette using the GUI

my_custom_palette<-choose_palette()
#play with the parameters and save

#now I have the function my_custom_palette
view(my_custom_palette)

function (n, h = c(255, 158), c = c(50, 80), l = c(20, 97), 
  power = c(2.04778156996587, 0.767918088737201), gamma = NULL, 
  fixup = TRUE, alpha = 1, palette = NULL, rev = FALSE, register = NULL, 
  ..., h1, h2, c1, l1, l2, p1, p2, cmax = NULL) 
{
  if (!is.null(gamma)) 
    warning("'gamma' is deprecated and has no effect")
  if (n < 1L) 
    return(character(0L))
  if (is.character(h)) 
    palette <- h
  pals <- if (!is.null(palette)) {
    as.matrix(hcl_palettes(type = "Diverging", palette = palette)[, 
      2L:11L])[1L, ]
  }
  else {
    structure(c(rep_len(h, 2L), c(c[1L], NA), rep_len(l, 
      2L), if (length(power) < 2L) c(power, NA) else rep_len(power, 
      2L), if (length(c) > 1L) c[2L] else NA, 1), .Names = vars.pal)
  }
  if (!missing(h) && !is.character(h)) {
    h <- rep_len(h, 2L)
    pals["h1"] <- h[1L]
    pals["h2"] <- h[2L]
  }
  if (!missing(c)) {
    pals["c1"] <- c[1L]
    if (length(c) > 1L) 
      pals["cmax"] <- c[2L]
  }
  if (!missing(l)) {
    l <- rep_len(l, 2L)
    pals["l1"] <- l[1L]
    pals["l2"] <- l[2L]
  }
  if (!missing(power)) {
    power <- if (length(power) < 2L) 
      c(power, NA)
    else rep_len(power, 2L)
    pals["p1"] <- power[1L]
    pals["p2"] <- power[2L]
  }
  if (!missing(fixup)) 
    pals["fixup"] <- as.logical(fixup)
  if (!missing(h1)) 
    pals["h1"] <- h1
  if (!missing(h2)) 
    pals["h2"] <- h2
  if (!missing(c1)) 
    pals["c1"] <- c1
  if (!missing(l1)) 
    pals["l1"] <- l1
  if (!missing(l2)) 
    pals["l2"] <- l2
  if (!missing(p1)) 
    pals["p1"] <- p1
  if (!missing(p2)) 
    pals["p2"] <- p2
  if (!missing(cmax)) 
    pals["cmax"] <- cmax
  pals["c2"] <- NA
  if (is.character(register) && nchar(register) > 0L) {
    add_hcl_pals(palette = register, type = "Diverging", 
      parameters = pals)
    register <- TRUE
  }
  else {
    register <- FALSE
  }
  if (is.na(pals["p2"])) 
    pals["p2"] <- pals["p1"]
  n2 <- ceiling(n/2)
  rval <- seq.int(1, by = -2/(n - 1), length.out = n2)
  rval <- c(seqhcl(rval, pals["h1"], pals["h1"], pals["c1"], 
    0, pals["l1"], pals["l2"], pals["p1"], pals["p2"], pals["cmax"], 
    as.logical(pals["fixup"]), ...), rev(seqhcl(rval, pals["h2"], 
    pals["h2"], pals["c1"], 0, pals["l1"], pals["l2"], pals["p1"], 
    pals["p2"], pals["cmax"], as.logical(pals["fixup"]), 
    ...)))
  if (floor(n/2) < n2) 
    rval <- rval[-n2]
  if (!missing(alpha)) {
    alpha <- pmax(pmin(alpha, 1), 0)
    alpha <- format(as.hexmode(round(alpha * 255 + 1e-04)), 
      width = 2L, upper.case = TRUE)
    rval <- ifelse(is.na(rval), NA, paste(rval, alpha, sep = ""))
  }
  if (rev) 
    rval <- rev(rval)
  if (register) 
    invisible(rval)
  else return(rval)
}
```

Now I suppose that with the function code I can create the palette in a shiny app without launch the GUI with choose_palette()

So, I type

```
my_custom_palette_2<-function (n, h = c(255, 158), c = c(50, 80), l = c(20, 97), 
  power = c(2.04778156996587, 0.767918088737201), gamma = NULL, 
  fixup = TRUE, alpha = 1, palette = NULL, rev = FALSE, register = NULL, 
  ..., h1, h2, c1, l1, l2, p1, p2, cmax = NULL) 
{
  if (!is.null(gamma)) 
    warning("'gamma' is deprecated and has no effect")
  if (n < 1L) 
    return(character(0L))
  if (is.character(h)) 
    palette <- h
  pals <- if (!is.null(palette)) {
    as.matrix(hcl_palettes(type = "Diverging", palette = palette)[, 
      2L:11L])[1L, ]
  }
  else {
    structure(c(rep_len(h, 2L), c(c[1L], NA), rep_len(l, 
      2L), if (length(power) < 2L) c(power, NA) else rep_len(power, 
      2L), if (length(c) > 1L) c[2L] else NA, 1), .Names = vars.pal)
  }
  if (!missing(h) && !is.character(h)) {
    h <- rep_len(h, 2L)
    pals["h1"] <- h[1L]
    pals["h2"] <- h[2L]
  }
  if (!missing(c)) {
    pals["c1"] <- c[1L]
    if (length(c) > 1L) 
      pals["cmax"] <- c[2L]
  }
  if (!missing(l)) {
    l <- rep_len(l, 2L)
    pals["l1"] <- l[1L]
    pals["l2"] <- l[2L]
  }
  if (!missing(power)) {
    power <- if (length(power) < 2L) 
      c(power, NA)
    else rep_len(power, 2L)
    pals["p1"] <- power[1L]
    pals["p2"] <- power[2L]
  }
  if (!missing(fixup)) 
    pals["fixup"] <- as.logical(fixup)
  if (!missing(h1)) 
    pals["h1"] <- h1
  if (!missing(h2)) 
    pals["h2"] <- h2
  if (!missing(c1)) 
    pals["c1"] <- c1
  if (!missing(l1)) 
    pals["l1"] <- l1
  if (!missing(l2)) 
    pals["l2"] <- l2
  if (!missing(p1)) 
    pals["p1"] <- p1
  if (!missing(p2)) 
    pals["p2"] <- p2
  if (!missing(cmax)) 
    pals["cmax"] <- cmax
  pals["c2"] <- NA
  if (is.character(register) && nchar(register) > 0L) {
    add_hcl_pals(palette = register, type = "Diverging", 
      parameters = pals)
    register <- TRUE
  }
  else {
    register <- FALSE
  }
  if (is.na(pals["p2"])) 
    pals["p2"] <- pals["p1"]
  n2 <- ceiling(n/2)
  rval <- seq.int(1, by = -2/(n - 1), length.out = n2)
  rval <- c(seqhcl(rval, pals["h1"], pals["h1"], pals["c1"], 
    0, pals["l1"], pals["l2"], pals["p1"], pals["p2"], pals["cmax"], 
    as.logical(pals["fixup"]), ...), rev(seqhcl(rval, pals["h2"], 
    pals["h2"], pals["c1"], 0, pals["l1"], pals["l2"], pals["p1"], 
    pals["p2"], pals["cmax"], as.logical(pals["fixup"]), 
    ...)))
  if (floor(n/2) < n2) 
    rval <- rval[-n2]
  if (!missing(alpha)) {
    alpha <- pmax(pmin(alpha, 1), 0)
    alpha <- format(as.hexmode(round(alpha * 255 + 1e-04)), 
      width = 2L, upper.case = TRUE)
    rval <- ifelse(is.na(rval), NA, paste(rval, alpha, sep = ""))
  }
  if (rev) 
    rval <- rev(rval)
  if (register) 
    invisible(rval)
  else return(rval)
}
```

For the 2 palettes the code is the same, by the first one, created with choose_palette(), works the second doesn't:

```
my_custom_palette(5)
[1] "#002F70" "#717B99" "#F6F6F6" "#518673" "#00421A"

my_custom_palette_2(5)
Error in my_custom_palette_2(5) : 
 promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

What is wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is the `h = c(255, 158), c = c(50, 80)` in the function definition. This works with the `NAMESPACE` semantics inside the `colorspace` package because it is clear that the function `c()` to be used for the definition of `h` is `base::c()`. In your custom code it is not clear and leads to a recursion because R tries to determine the value of the `c` argument first.

But there is a simpler solution to your problem. Using the parameters you selected you can simply compute the colors from the palette via

```
diverging_hcl(5, h = c(255, 158), c = c(50, 80),
  l = c(20, 97), power = c(2.05, 0.77))
## [1] "#002F70" "#717B99" "#F6F6F6" "#528673" "#00421A"
```

Alternatively, you can also register the palette with a name and use that subsequently:

```
diverging_hcl(5, h = c(255, 158), c = c(50, 80),
  l = c(20, 97), power = c(2.05, 0.77), register = "mypal")
diverging_hcl(5, "mypal")
## [1] "#002F70" "#717B99" "#F6F6F6" "#528673" "#00421A"
```

You can also put the latter call into your `.Rprofile` so that you have the palette available every time you start R.

The option via registration is also pointed out explicitly in the shiny version of `hclwizard()`/`choose_palette()` in the > Export > Register tab on the right. In the Tcl/Tk version you can also register the palette in the "Register" tab at the top.

Note that in any case the resulting palette can be tweaked further, e.g.,

```
diverging_hcl(5, "mypal", c = 0)
## [1] "#303030" "#6B7BA6" "#F6F6F6" "#338A6F" "#303030"
```

Comment: `c = c(50, 80)` <--- this is bonkers.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. After exporting the function for a custom palette (defined and exported within the GUI) there is no way to subsequently use that definition. You gave an important hint; the issue is the namespace conflict. However, there is no obvious way to get the code for `my_custom_palette` into the colorspace namespace, without rerunning the GUI.

Comment: How is the returned value from `colorspace:::choose_palette_tcltk` assigned to the colorspace namespace? Is it invisibly registered somehow? I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: It's stored in an environment within the colorspace package. Thus, each time you load the package namespace the environment gets initialized again and you need to re-run the registration code. It's s not necessary though to do that via the GUI. That's why I suggested to put the coffee into the .Rprofile.

Comment: If I understand, the user is meant to take the `h` `c` `l` and `power` arguments out of the result from the GUI, and plug those into a call to `diverging_hcl` with the desired `n` to generate a palette? I don't see the need to put it in .Rprofile. Normally I make my scripts self contained.

Comment: Achim, I appreciate your comments.  Although I think this is hard to use within the normal R workflow, I still deeply appreciate your work, it's absolutely indispensable. Colors are so important but complicated and require specialized knowledge. I've spent many hours trying to understand colors in R.

Comment: Yes, the `h`/`c`/`l`/`power` values should be passed to `diverging_hcl`. If you want to use the colors once, then there is no need to register the palette. If you want to use it repeatedly, especially with different values of `n`, then registration is handy. If you want the colors to be "always" available, then `.Rprofile` is one possibility to put them.

Comment: If this misses the point of your inquiry or there are still problems with the solution, it might be easier to edit/clarify the question or ask a new one. There's only so much you can explain in the comments. (And things might be more difficult when answering on the phone ... like overlooking the autocorrection of "code" to "coffee" in my first comment above, sigh.)

Comment: Code, coffee, covfefe; same, same, and same.
This has been helpful. I thought I was doing something wrong with the pal output in hcl_wizard() all this time.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved with the function proposed by @Achim Zeileis in this way:
whit all the parameters selected from the GUI I created this function

```
`custom_color_palette<-function(n){colorspace::diverge_hcl(n, gamma = NULL,fixup = TRUE, alpha = 1, palette = NULL, rev = FALSE, register = NULL, h1=255, h2=119, c1=53,l1=33,l2=82,p1=.01,p2=1.3, cmax = 93)}
`
```

In this way I can recall it in the plot, specifying the numbers of distinct colors that I need:

```
plot_ly(x=x,y=y,color=group,colors=custom_color_palette(5))
```

Comment: You can either use the vector arguments `h`, `c`, `l`, and `power` or the scalar `h1`, `h2`, `c1`, etc. But there is no need to repeat the selected coordinates in both arguments. Also, please accept my answer or your own answer here on SO so that the question is marked as resolved.